# Push file from local system to android device in automation script using UIAutomator

Tags: adb, android-uiautomator

I need to push a file to android device from my local system through automation script using UIAutomator.

I have tried, using below code:

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process pr=rt.exec("cmd /C start C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\CopyfilesToDevice.bat");
 pr.waitFor();
 int exitValue=pr.exitValue();
```

Batch file "CopyfilesToDevice.bat" contains adb push command as mentioned below

```
adb push D:\xys\myfile.dat /data/local/tmp
```

The above code is executing successfully but the file is not copying to the device storage (data/local/tmp/).

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in Advance!!!
Mra

Comment: Open your console and run the adb command from there. If the file is not copied, I'm sure that you'll see some error message.

Comment: No, It runs perfectly from console. I found the problem. The code that i have mentioned above is part of the UIAutomator test script which executes with in the device as a test app. So, when it executes within the device, it doesn't know the path of my system (i.e D:\xys\myfile.dat).  adb push command will work fine from desktop system to device, but it doesn't work when it is executed from within the device.